# Error while saving some variables into a binary file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to do this hospital management program to a school work and i'm having this error and really have no idea how to solve it. I'd appreciate someone to guide me. 
Thank in advance.

I have this linked list:

```
struct marcacao
{
  char nome[50];
  int idade;
  struct marcacao *next;
};
```

That is created using this function

```
void make_apt(struct marcacao **head_apt)

struct marcacao tmp;
...
  while( *head_apt )
    head_apt = &(*head_apt)->next;
...
printf("Nome do Paciente > ");
scanf(" %[^\n]", tmp.nome);
printf("Idade do Paciente > ");
scanf("%d", &tmp.idade);

tmp.next = NULL;

if ( !(*head_apt = malloc( sizeof (**head_apt) ) ) )
{
  printf("Erro a alocar novo no ");
  return;
}
**head_apt = tmp;
...
```

And i have to save the info in a binary file, so it can be resumed in the next execution.

```
void sv_apt(struct marcacao *head_apt)

FILE *f = fopen(APT_FILE, "wb");
...

while(head_apt)
{
  fwrite(head_apt->nome, sizeof(head_apt->nome), 1, f);
  fwrite(&head_apt->idade, sizeof(head_apt->idade), 1, f);
  head_apt = head_apt->next;
}
```

But valgrind is shoing this:

```
==18255== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==18255==    at 0x4F22710: __write_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==18255==    by 0x4EAFF02: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1261)
==18255==    by 0x4EB13DB: new_do_write (fileops.c:538)
==18255==    by 0x4EB13DB: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:511)
==18255==    by 0x4EB0C5F: _IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:165)
==18255==    by 0x4EA4A4F: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:59)
==18255==    by 0x401CD3: sv_apt (apt.c:125)
==18255==    by 0x401A11: make_appointment (apt.c:43)
==18255==    by 0x400B20: main (main.c:31)
==18255==  Address 0x402700c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18255==
```

And using an hex editor I can  see that the info is not well saved.

Comment: You appear to be mixing *apples* and *oranges*. `struct marcacao tmp;` appears to be declared local to a function with automatic storage. It is then assigned as a node in your linked-ist. When you try and write the value in another part of your code, it croaks because it can't find the node (or nodes) that you assigned to the list using `tmp`. However, it is impossible to be sure without an ***MCVE***. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (then myself or someone else can help further)

Comment: Additionally, `valgrind` seems to be saying exactly that. That `Address 0x402700c is not stack'd, malloc'd, ...` (it isn't seen as memory currently in use or recently freed). The problem is generate within your code by calls in `main()` to a function `make_appointment()` at the lines and in the files shown in `(file.c:line no.)`.

Comment: Note: `scanf(" %[^\n]", tmp.nome);` is as unsafe as `gets(tmp.nome)`.  Using `fgets()` would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

you need to understand the idea of 'serialization'. That is storing data in a file (or on the wire) and reading it back. You cannot just dump stuff into a file (except in rare v simple cases).

You need to choose a serialization format. I would recommend ASCII based stuff cos its easy to edit and debug. Use json, xml or yaml.

Comment: Except that in this case, you can easily dump a linked-list of `struct marcacao` to disk in binary format and read it back into a list without issue.

Comment: you will have to convert the 'next' pointers to some abstract pointer concept and convert back, since they will not be loaded into the same address

Comment: No, I think that is where we are not communicating. I see your point. I'm not talking about writing the pointers out to the file, just each struct (all members are using automatic storage, so there are no pointer concerns) I would just write all nodes out, then on the read, simply read an instance of the struct and call `add_node` to rebuild the list. You are correct, you can't write the node or next addresses to file and hope to read those back in.